# Print form on current record and records after current record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple SelectRecord/PrintSelected macro button to print the current record open on the form. The current record has a numeric textbox on the form named [Aantal], if [Aantal] has value 5, I want the print button to print the current record and the next 4 records after that, so 5 total.

I thought maybe something like this in the print VBA code.

```
Dim db As Database                  'Current database.
Dim lng As Long                     'Loop controller.
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset             'Table to append to.
Const conMaxRecords As Long = 20    'Number of records you want.

Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Aantal")
With rs
    For lng = 1 To conMaxRecords
        .AddNew
            !CountID = lng
        .Update
    Next
End With
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
MakeData = "Records created."
```

Comment: Exactly how did you think this code would print 5 records? It simply adds 20 records to a table. But maybe on right track. Open recordset, find record with ID of current record on form, write that ID and the 4 ID's that follow to a 'temp' table. Build query that joins temp table with data table and print report bound to query. Don't forget to purge the temp table first each time code runs.

Comment: @June7 5 is example, could be 20, but I am very new to this. Thanks I will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that needs it, if your record has a column containing an amount. Let's say 5.
And you are standing on the first record, then this will print that first record and the 4 records after that, so total 5.

This is usefull if you have multiple records created after each other as a group, so they can be printed as a group instead of printing all records or doing it one by one.

Change: **AantalForm** to your textbox on the form containing the amount.

```
Private Sub PrintFrm_Click()
On Error GoTo 0
Dim t1 As Integer
Dim t2 As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim frm As Form
Dim pgn As Integer
pgn = Me.CurrentRecord
t1 = Nz(Me.AantalForm, 1)

If t1 > 1 Then
t2 = pgn + t1 - 1

For j = pgn To t2
    DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
Next j
Exit Sub
Else
t2 = 0
DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```